# C - Multiple Bar Sliders

Tags: c

I have a program which has multiple sliders than can be controlled using the 
A and D Keys to Increase/Decrease the value, and W and S to Choose which Bar to control. Everything works, changing values and even controlling different sliders, but I can't change which slider to control. I have a variable named "BarChosen" which is used to use the array of whatever Bar it is on, so if BarChosen = 0 then you can control Bar 0.

To Print The Bars

```
void BarValues(int Bar, int BarLeft,char UserInput) {
for (int i = 0; i < Bar; i++) {
    printf("|");
}

for (int i = 0; i < BarLeft; i++) {
    printf(".");
}

printf(" - %d\n", Bar);

}
```

To Control

```
void UpdateBar(char UserInput,int BarChosen,int Bar[3], int BarLeft[3]) {
if (UserInput == 'a' || UserInput == 'A') {
    if (Bar[BarChosen] <= 0) {

    }
    else {
        Bar[BarChosen]--;
        BarLeft[BarChosen]++;
    }
}

else if (UserInput == 'd' || UserInput == 'D') {
    if (Bar[BarChosen] >= 30) {

    }
    else {
        Bar[BarChosen]++;
        BarLeft[BarChosen]--;
    }
}

else if (UserInput == 'w' || UserInput == 'W') {
    if (BarChosen <= 0) {

    }
    else {
        BarChosen--;
    }

}

else if (UserInput == 's' || UserInput == 'S') {
    if (BarChosen >= 3) {

    }
    else {
        BarChosen++;
    }

  }
}
```

Main Method

```
int main(void)
{
char UserInput = '0';
int BarLeft[3] = { 30, 20, 10 };
int Bar[3] = { 0, 10, 20 };
int i = 0;
int BarChosen = 0;

do {
    system("cls");
    printf("Bar Chosen: %d\n", BarChosen);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        BarValues(Bar[i], BarLeft[i], UserInput);
    }
    UserInput = getch();
    UpdateBar(UserInput, BarChosen, Bar, BarLeft);

} while (1);


//Stall
getch();
return 0;
}
```

My issue is that, BarChosen doesn't change. I have tested the functions to print and check if they are activated, and they are, yet BarChosen does not change and stays at 0

Comment: Aside: please note that Windows `getch` returns `int`, like most input functions, but I notice function `BarValues` doesn't use that argument.

Comment: But the controls still work using char UserInput. My real issue is that everything else is updating except for the BarChosen integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does "call by value", so when you call UpdateBar() from main(), you are initializing a local variable in UpdateBar() named BarChosen.

Simplest change is to have UpdateBar() return the new value of BarChosen, and call it from main as

```
BarChosen = UpdateBar(UserInput, BarChosen, Bar, BarLeft);
```

Comment: I see, but why are the values in the arrays updating? Is this due to arrays being pointers?

Comment: Correct, you  are passing in pointers and then updating the caller's array.  The way to think of it is that you are always doing "call by value" but sometimes the value is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

so taking the advice of Dave Goldberg, I decided to use pointers in order to solve this issue.

Pointer to BarChosen

```
int BarChosen = 0;
int *BarPointer = 0;
BarPointer = &BarChosen;
```

Updated the Parameters to include the pointer

```
void UpdateBar(char UserInput,int BarChosen,int Bar[3], int BarLeft[3],int *BarPointer)
```

Added the pointer when the controls are confirmed to change the value of the BarChosen integer.

```
else if (UserInput == 'w' || UserInput == 'W') {
    if (BarChosen <= 0) {

    }
    else {
        BarChosen--;
        *BarPointer = BarChosen;
    }

}

else if (UserInput == 's' || UserInput == 'S') {
    if (BarChosen >= 2) {

    }
    else {
        BarChosen++;
        *BarPointer = BarChosen;

    }

}
```